# Отсортируйте по возрастанию поле и выведите 5 строк sql

Tags: sql

из таблицы

```
CREATE DATABASE seminar_3;
use seminar_3;
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(15),
surname VARCHAR(15),
speciality  VARCHAR(15),
seniority INT,
sallary INT,
age INT);
 
INSERT INTO 
    staff (name, surname, speciality, seniority, sallary, age)
VALUES
    ("Вася", "Васькин", "начальник", 40, 100000, 60),
    ("Петя", "Петькин", "начальник", 8, 70000, 30),
    ("Катя", "Катькин", "инженер", 2, 70000, 25),
    ("Саша", "Сашкин", "инженер", 12, 50000, 35),
    ("Иван", "Иванов", "рабочий", 40, 30000, 59),
    ("Петр", "Петров", "рабочий", 20, 250000, 40),
    ("Сидор", "Сидоров", "рабочий", 10, 20000, 35),
    ("Антон", "Антонов", "рабочий", 8, 19000, 28),
    ("Юра", "Юркин", "рабочий", 5, 15000, 25),
    ("Максим", "Воронин", "рабочий", 2, 11000, 22),
    ("Юра", "Галкин", "рабочий", 3, 12000, 24),
    ("Люся", "Люськина", "уборщик", 10, 10000, 49);
```

Нужно Отсортировать по возрастанию поле “Зарплата” и выведите 5 строк с наибольшей заработной платой (возможен подзапрос)

Делаю запрос на вывод 5 максимальных зарплат:

```
SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY sallary DESC LIMIT 5;
```

И как поотом их отсортировать по возрастанию?

Comment: Так, например `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY sallary DESC LIMIT 5) t ORDER BY t.sallary ASC`, первое что в голову приходит, скорее всего есть лучший вариант

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY sallary DESC LIMIT 5) AS sallary ORDER BY sallary;
```

возможно есть другие варианты.

Comment: Фактически это решение указал InDevX в комментарии.